# Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.activate

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, exception

I have the following code working perfectly as desired... It completes all the tasks as expected but still populates a red error box advising me of an Exception. It's definitely completing all of the tasks, so I can't tell what I've got wrong in here but maybe I'm just using the wrong syntax somewhere? I'd appreciate any help.

**Error Message:** *Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.activate*

[Here is a link to my example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17bTMTUiXenOnw3kmu1Ax5-CjmiOIChJKmb8t4a_r6Q8/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function AddRoutedOptions() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.alert(
      'Add all Routed tasks to the Project Tracker?',
      'Are you sure you want to add all Routed tasks to the Project Tracker?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
  var pglc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pre-Go Live Checklist');
  var vcc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Video Course Checklist');
  var rsc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Routed Setup Checklist').activate();
    pglc.getRange('B32:B35').copyTo(pglc.getRange('E23:E26'), {contentsOnly:true});
    vcc.getRange('B32:C37').copyTo(vcc.getRange('G10:H15'), {contentsOnly:true});
    rsc.activate('Routed Setup Checklist');
} else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('No tasks were added.');
  }
}

function RemoveRoutedOptions() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.alert(
      'Remove all Routed tasks from the Project Tracker?',
      'Are you sure you want to remove all Routed tasks from the Project Tracker?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
  var pglc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pre-Go Live Checklist');
  var vcc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Video Course Checklist');
  var rsc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Routed Setup Checklist').hideSheet();
    pglc.getRange('E23:E26').clearContent();
    vcc.getRange('G10:H15').clearContent();
    rsc.hideSheet('Routed Setup Checklist');
} else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('No tasks were removed.')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheet.activate() does not accept parameters

```
rsc.activate('Routed Setup Checklist');
```

[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate())

Try changing this:

```
var rsc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Routed Setup Checklist').activate();
    pglc.getRange('B32:B35').copyTo(pglc.getRange('E23:E26'), {contentsOnly:true});
    vcc.getRange('B32:C37').copyTo(vcc.getRange('G10:H15'), {contentsOnly:true});
    rsc.activate('Routed Setup Checklist');
```

to this:

```
var rsc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Routed Setup Checklist');
    pglc.getRange('B32:B35').copyTo(pglc.getRange('E23:E26'), {contentsOnly:true});
    vcc.getRange('B32:C37').copyTo(vcc.getRange('G10:H15'), {contentsOnly:true});
    rsc.activate();
```

Comment: ty so much! That absolutely did the trick! I misunderstood how I should be handling that and your documentation helped too.